# Sometimes keypress method is not being implemented

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

in my c# win-form application, i use a user-defined calculator win-form which can be used either by mouse clicking or keyboard numpad. I get buttons clicking by mouse but cannot get keystrokes by "keypress" method of the Form.

Actually, keypress method works when program first starts but after a couple of keystroke, the keypress method doesn't catch the keystokes. I tested using breakpoints but the breakpoits are not implemented either after a while.

Form's keypreview property is set to true. I tested also with and without " e.Handled = true;" but doesn't make sense. Any answer will be appreciated.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string key = "";
    if (textBox1.Text.Equals("UNDEFINED")) textBox1.Text = "0";
    else if (textBox1.Text.Equals("ERROR") || textBox1.Text == "FULL")
    {
        textBox2.Text = " ";
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }

    switch ((int)e.KeyChar)
    {
        case 8: BtnEraser(); lastWork= "btnErase"; break;// Backspace (erase);
        case 13:
        case 42:
        case 43:
        case 45:
        case 47:
            key = (int)e.KeyChar == 13 ? "Enter" : e.KeyChar.ToString(); BtnWork(key);
            lastWork= key.Equals("Enter") ? "btnEqual" : "btnAdd"; break; // equal or math operations

        case 27: textBox1.Text = "0"; textBox2.Text = " "; lastWork= "btnC"; break;// btnCe;

        case 44: textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Comma(); lastWork= "btnComma"; break;

        case 48:
        case 49:
        case 50:
        case 51:
        case 52:
        case 53:
        case 54:
        case 55:
        case 56:
        case 57:
            BtnNumber(e.KeyChar.ToString());
            lastWork= "btn5"; break; // 0-9 Number-entry

        default:
            break;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: The KeyPress event is only ever raised on the control that has the focus, KeyPreview does not change that.  That *could* be the form, but that will be a complete accident, that textbox and the buttons are going to slurp it quickly and you can't set the focus back.  KeyPress is useful for controls that accept text, the TextBox control is the boilerplate example.  You do not actually want text, you want letters that match the buttons.  Override the form's ProcessDialogChar() method instead.  Beware of keypad keys.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used that and it works. I also added "if(EventArgs.ToString().Equals("System.EventArgs")) statement" to button click methods in order to separate Mouse Events or Keyboard Events. Otherwise, button click method is always implemented when i press enter key.